# Reset button clicked state in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

In my mobile web page I wrote handler for a button to reject all clicks after a single click is made and that request is processed by network:

```
$(this).unbind().bind('click', function() {
            return false;
        });
```

I have a button in my other web page, which takes me to:

```
history.back()
```

problem is that when I come back to my prev page, my clicked button won't work again as I had handled it for monkey clicks.
Is there any state, like clicked, which can be reset on click or my back button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle a single click to an element I would use the jquery [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method as it will only fire once. Your button handler could be written like this and the custom code you wrote above to return false can be removed:

```
$('button').one('click', function () {
   // Handle single click of button here
});
```

When you click the back button you will need to rebind that event to the button. I'd just wrap that code in a function and then call it wherever you call `history.back()`:

```
function HandleSingleButtonClick() {
   $('button').one('click', function () {
      // Handle single click of button here
   });
}
```

Then right after your history.back call the function:

```
history.back();
HandleSingleButtonClick();
```

Comment: here also if i come back to page with     data-rel ="back" my button on fist page wont work :(